# How to pass and translate with the language selected option in other component using ngx-translate

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

Using **ngx-translate** library for localization. It is working fine in the component where I am have placed. *Scenario:* I have created a component for select language dropdown and I am calling the component in Login component and using there. It's working fine. Now, I want to transfer the language selected to all other component after login.

I don't want to use select language option on each and every place. The language selected in Login page should reflect on other pages as well. How can I achieve this ? *(I don't have other module as of now)*

**i18nService.ts :**

```
currentLang = 'en';
  translateService: TranslateService;

  setSelectedLanguage(language:any) {
    this.currentLang = language;
    this.applyLanguage(this.currentLang);
  }
  private applyLanguage(language:any) {
    this.translateService.use(language);
  }
  getLanguages() {
    return this.translateService.getLangs();
  }

  constructor(translateService: TranslateService) {
    this.translateService = translateService;
  }

  setUpConf() {
    this.translateService.addLangs(['en', 'te', 'kn', 'hi']);
    this.translateService.setDefaultLang(this.currentLang);
    this.applyLanguage(this.currentLang);
  }
```

**LanguageDropdown.ts**

```
i18nConf: I18nConfigService;

  constructor(i18nConf: I18nConfigService) { 
    this.i18nConf = i18nConf;
    this.i18nConf.setUpConf();
  }
```

**LanguageDropdown.html**

```
<select class="form-input col-md-2" #langSelect
        (change)="i18nConf.setSelectedLanguage(langSelect.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let lang of i18nConf.getLanguages()" [value]="lang"
            [selected]="lang === this.i18nConf.currentLang">
            {{ lang }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually get the used language via the `TranslateService`. In the API you have the `currentLang` attribute which should give you the currently applied language: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#properties

> currentLang: The lang currently used

To use this in other components, you need to import the `TranslateService` of course.

To use you need to call it like this:

```
// This will contain the currently set language
const currentLang = this.translateService.currentLang;
```

If you want to translate things, you have multiple ways. One way is the [get](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#5-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive) method.

```
this.translateService.get('Message Not Found').subscribe(translation => {
  console.log(translation); // Here should be the translation
});
```

The other way (my preferred way) is to use the [translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#5-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive) pipe:

```
<button mat-raised-button
        color="primary"
        (click)="confirm()">
  {{ 'Yes' | translate }}
</button>
```

Comment: Any example to use `currentLang` from `TranslateService` ? How can I use this currentLang in other component HTML and Ts file ? I am able to get language code using   `currentLang` now.

Comment: Yeah, this was the question, right? How to get the language in other components

Or do you wanted to translate stuff in other components?

Comment: I want to translate stuffs as well in other component

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: So, in short `translateService` know what language has been selected. And I can use this `translateService` in ts like `this.translateService.instant('Yes');` in other component directly?

Comment: Yes, that's why you set the language in the first place. This will remain in the service state, so normally you should be able to use it in all components in the same module. If you import it correctly to child modules then you should be able to use it there as well

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks it working now.